# Add onclick button to onkeyup function in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick, onkeyup

```js
function sendMessage(e){

    if (e.which == 13 && ! e.shiftKey) {
        var id = $('#form-message-write input').val();
        var message = $('#form-message-write textarea').val();

        if (message.trim() != '') {
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('id', id);
            data.append('message', message);

            $.ajax({
                url: BASE_URL + '/direct-messages/send',
                type: "POST",
                timeout: 5000,
                data: data,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF},
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.code == 200) {
                        $('.dm .chat .message-list .alert').remove();
                        $('#form-message-write textarea').val("");
                        $('.dm .chat .message-list').append(response.html);
                        $(".dm .chat .message-list").animate({ scrollTop: $('.dm .chat .message-list').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
                    } else {
                        $('#errorMessageModal').modal('show');
                        $('#errorMessageModal #errors').html('Something went wrong!');
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#errorMessageModal').modal('show');
                    $('#errorMessageModal #errors').html('Something went wrong!');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
 <div id="message_write_box" class="message-write">
   <form id="form-message-write">
     <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $friend->id }}">
       @if ($can_send_message)

        <textarea id="personal_message" class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="Your message.." onkeyup="sendMessage(event)"></textarea>

       @else

        <div class="alert alert-danter">You must follow each other to send messages!</div>
      @endif
   </form>
 </div>
```

Hi guys Ive been trying to play around with this code and Javascript is a new world for me. Could anyone help me to understand how to convert this onkeyup to an onclick event? Thank you for any help! I just need help to understand what's missing? maybe I need to add an event listener? I’ve tried a few different things but I can’t get a button to function. I'm sure the solution is simple, I just need to take the text inside the textarea and apply a button to send the user input.

Have tried a button, have tried an input field, have tried eventlistener, but I’m still obviously doing something wrong.

The entire function works perfectly as the onkeyup.

Answer (score 0):

First, add button element to the HTML. For this button either add onclick attribute with the sendMessage(event) function or add event listener and attach it to that button and call the sendMessage(event) function in the listener.

Second, you will need to remove the "if (e.which == 13 && ! e.shiftKey) {" condition which checks for key press (up). Since you want to trigger the sendMessage function on click you may not need this condition at all so you can remove it. The rest of the code should work as it is.

Comment: Thank you for replying.. I added a button to the form with onclick="sendMessage(event)", I removed the 'if (e.which == 13 && ! e.shiftKey)' condition, but still nothing happens when the button is clicked.

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-submit" onclick="sendMessage(event)"></button>

Comment: There might be problem with the message, the value. You are checking for non-zero length. Take a look if at the moment of click the value is not empty, null or undefined. You can add log to print the message to ensure this check goes through.